# Converting from A to B using VIM

Tags: vim

I'm looking for some guidance on something Ive been working on. Im trying to convert three different formats of data into a formatted data.

This is the data I need to convert:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL        00100     C                    N12345678W1234567891234       GND   99999MMY LITTLE TEST                000000000
ABCDEFGHIJKL        00100     H N12345678W123456789                              GND   99999MANOTHER LITTLE TEST           000000000
ABCDEFGHIJKL        00200     L N12345678W123456789N12345678W12345678912341234                                             000000000
ABCDEFGHIJKL        00300     G N12345678W123456789                                                                        000000000
```

This is the output I would like:

```
0010|C|||N12345678|W123456789|123.4
0010|H|N12345678|W123456789||
0020|L|N12345678|W123456789|N12345678|W123456789|123.4|123.4
0030|G|N12345678|W123456789|
```

I have mapped the insert button with:

```
map <Insert> :%s/...................................................$/<ESC> :%s/....................//<ESC> :%s/0     G /\|G\|/e<ESC> :%s/0     C /\|C\|/e<ESC> :%s/0     H /\|H\|/e<ESC>  :%s/0     L /\|L\|/e<ESC>  :%s/0     R /\|R\|/e<ESC> :%s/e0/\|E0/ge<ESC> :%s/w0/\|W0/ge<ESC> :%s/w1/\|W1/ge<ESC> :%s/    /\|\|<ESC> :%s/e1/\|E1/ge<ESC>  :%s/               //e<ESC>:%s/\s\+$//<ESC> :%s#\d\{4}$#\=printf('\|%.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 10.0)#e<ESC>
```

And am converting with slight limitations as I get the following:

```
0010|C|||N12345678|W123456789|123.4
0010|H|N12345678|W123456789||
0020|L|N12345678|W123456789N12345678|W1234567891234|123.4
0030|G|N12345678|W123456789||
```

The letters after the first four digits can either be G, C, H, L or R hence the code ive made takes that into account. The letters infront of the 12345678 are compass directions and therfore can be N, S, E or W.

My problem with the code is if I use find and replace to change N to |N then it replaces all and adds two || before the first N it finds. Also the | and the decimal for when there are an arc drawn and is either and L or R.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Gets rid of extra characters at end:

```
:%s/...................................................$/<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra characters at beginning:

```
:%s/....................//<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra spaces and adds a | infront and after the initial letter:

```
:%s/0     G /\|G\|/e<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra spaces and adds a | infront and after the initial letter:

```
:%s/0     C /\|C\|/e<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra spaces and adds a | infront and after the initial letter:

```
 :%s/0     H /\|H\|/e<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra spaces and adds a | infront and after the initial letter:

```
:%s/0     L /\|L\|/e<ESC>
```

Gets rid of extra spaces and adds a | infront and after the initial letter:

```
:%s/0     R /\|R\|/e<ESC>
```

Adds a | infront of the compass direction for coordinate

```
:%s/e0/\|E0/ge<ESC>
```

Adds a | infront of the compass direction for coordinate

```
:%s/w0/\|W0/ge<ESC>
```

Adds a | infront of the compass direction for coordinate

```
:%s/w1/\|W1/ge<ESC>
```

Adds || for when dealing with a single set of co-ordinate

```
:%s/    /\|\|<ESC>
```

Adds a | infront of the compass direction for coordinate

```
:%s/e1/\|E1/ge<ESC>
```

Not wuite sure why I put this in:

```
:%s/               //e<ESC>
```

Gets rid of any white spaces and trailing characters:

```
:%s/\s\+$//<ESC>
```

when drawing a circle using the C or arcs using the L/R then it converts the end digits to decimal and adds the | infront to separate it:

```
:%s#\d\{4}$#\=printf('\|%.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 10.0)#e<ESC>
```

Comment: using awk would be easier...

Comment: Please break down your mapping, split it over multiple lines, and tell us what (you think) each line does. Also, why do you end each command with `<ESC>` instead of `<CR>`?

Comment: Ive added a break down of the mapped key code ive already created, I need to figure out how to convert the first lot of decimals when dealing with sequences starting with L or R. The other issue is I cant get a | in front of the extra co-ordinates so came up with this: :%s/L.....................N/......................\|N/e<ESC> But this replaces it with dots any idea how to use dots as any character just so I replace the ones i need?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `gawk` (GNU awk). You can use the `FIELDWIDTH` variable to set the widths of each field separated by spaces.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="12 8 5 5 1 1 9 10 9 10 4 4"; OFS="|"} { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i); }; x=""; if ($11) { x = $11/10;} y=""; if ($12) { x = $12/10;} print $3, $5, $7, $8, $9, $10, x, y; }' file.txt
```

More human readable:

```
BEGIN {
        FIELDWIDTHS="12 8 5 5 1 1 9 10 9 10 4 4";
        OFS="|"
}

{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i);
        }
        x="";
        if ($11) {
                x = $11/10;
        }
        y="";
        if ($12) {
                y = $12/10;
        }
        print $3, $5, $7, $8, $9, $10, x, y;
}
```

Note: This is a slightly different output format that what you gave.

You can use the filter command, `:!`, to make a mapping.